# Drupal challenges for learning

Tags: 8

For newbie Drupal developers:

Is there a repo, blog post or similar with increasing difficulty challenges?

I am willing to test my skills, which may be more than basic.

It would be nice to have a learn path.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions explicitly asking to recommend, find or compare a module, theme, distribution, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers. Research and testing needs to be done before asking a question. Please describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have all felt like a newbie at something. Usually, that means our brains are growing. I recently read an inspiring article about this very thing:

http://paulgraham.com/noob.html

Anyway, if you're just looking for a repo with coding examples, then the [Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) project is literally what you have described.

As far as tutorials, there are quite a few to choose from.

Start with [Acquia Academy](https://training.acquia.com/). Their tutorials are quick, linear, and easy to follow, and they also have some free training materials. **UPDATE:** Actually it looks like [a lot of the good stuff](https://www.youtube.com/user/AcquiaTV/playlists) *is* free! I didn't know, because I was always logging in through an employer account.

[Drupalize.me](https://drupalize.me) used to be really good. Their Drupal 7 courses are very well organized and easy to follow in a linear fashion. Unfortunately, their D8 courses are not as good. D8 has changed a lot since they wrote the tutorials and they haven't necessarily updated them. Also, they are not as well structured and you might start to feel lost in a labyrinth of forking paths. Still, some of their content is available for free, and you can learn quite a lot if you just start with that and keep in mind that it might have changed since Drupal 8.1 or whatever.

There are a ton of other tutorials out there. Some of my favorites are at [codekarate.com](https://codekarate.com) but as with [Drupalize.me](https://drupalize.me) the Drupal 7 material is far more comprehensive. The D8 material is good, but tends to be less of a broad overview and more of a deep dive into specific niche things.

This list is far from complete. You’ll find a million other tutorials on DuckDuckGo (or Google, if that’s how you roll)

If you really want to learn Drupal 8 (and 9) development, you might actually want to start by taking a course on MVC development with the Symfony framework. I guess Symfony 3 is still the place to start (although with D9 fast approaching everybody is learning Symfony 4) so here’s a likely option:

https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-symfony-3-framework-by-practical-examples/